# powershell hyper-v natswitch no internet

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I created a hyper-v natswitch with powershell

```
New-VMSwitch –SwitchName “NAT-Switch” –SwitchType Internal –Verbose
Get-NetAdapter
New-NetIPAddress –IPAddress 192.168.200.1 -PrefixLength 24 -InterfaceIndex 60 –Verbose
New-NetNAT -Name "NATNetwork" -InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix 192.168.200.0/24 -Verbose
```

assigned a guest vm to the switch and gave it an ip address

[image]

but I can't get to the internet...

I can ping google.com from the guest vm

[image]

but I can't get to google.com

[image]

I'm not sure what else to try.

Ubuntu doesn't work either -

[image]

I've been looking at this for days...does anyone have any suggestions?  I'd really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

No idea why this didn't work...

As a workaround, I ended up adding a pfsense firewall on hypervisor and adding the ubuntu host to the internal network(natted) side of the pfsense.

Works great now.